Исправление компенсации планировщика (AioSchedule)
У меня есть тг-бот, написанный на aiogram-3.x с использованием Redis. Одна из функций бота — отправка пользователю уведомлений в указанное время.
Вот функция планирования задачи:
scheduler_uvedoml.add_job(
    send_motivational_message,
    'cron',
    day_of_week=day,
    hour=adjusted_time.hour,
    minute=adjusted_time.minute,
    kwargs={'user_id': telegram_id},
    id=f'{telegram_id}/{day}:{time}',
    misfire_grace_time=None, 
)

Проблема заключается в том, что если у меня запланирована задача, и она не выполняется по причине выключенного кода, то в момент включения кода задача сразу же выполнится в качестве компенсации за невыполненную, причём в какое время будет перезапущен код — не важно.
Мне же нужно, чтобы она не присылалась сразу после перезапуска в случае пропуска задачи по причине отключенного кода. Также нужно, чтобы не было отсрочки у следующей задачи — она должна приходить строго по расписанию.
